# How to remove all first item into a List<int[]>

Tags: c#, linq

In a foreach i select all the first item from a list type `List<int[]>` using this line:

```
var selectData = arrayList.Select(x => x.First());
```

Where z is a List
I want to use the same method to remove all the first item but because int[] is not a delegate type it's not working

```
arrayList.Remove(x => x.First())
```

Do you have an idea using linq?

< Transform the array to a list is possbile >

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove the first items in every array(you can't modify an array):

```
for(int i = 0; i < arrayList.Count; i++)
    arrayList[i] = arrayList[i].Skip(1).ToArray();
```

Comment: Imagine if i transform the array into a list? Is that possible?

Comment: It's working :)
Nice to set array with another array with the skip :)

Answer (score 5):

for each `y` you can set the list to itself skipping the first item

```
x.y[i].z = x.y[i].z.Skip(1).ToList();
```

**Edit:** After question update

```
arrayList = arrayList.Select(x => x.Skip(1).ToArray()).ToList();
```

Comment: The idea is to remove inside the array not the array. I mean if the first item array is [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], 0 have to be remove.
I test your code and it remove the first array. I Don't understand why peopel upvote your answer

Comment: @MatDev8 they upvoted my answer because it answers your question before you updated it `var test= x.y[i].z.Remove(x => x.First())`, it shows you want to remove the first element from z of each y[i]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove:

```
x.y[i].z.Remove(x.y[i].z.First());
```

If you want to just get the result without the first item, without actually modifying the list:

```
var selectionOfAllButTheFirst = x.y[i].z.Skip(1).ToList();
```

Answer (score -3):

`resultlist.RemoveAt(1)` where 1 its a position or index

Comment: `List<int>` has a zero-based index. `RemoveAt(1)` removes the second entry, not the first.